# Update Panel timer control and JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, sharepoint2010-bcs

We have our controls in Update Panel like HTML div, tabel , grid and we have AsyncPostBackTrigger with Event Tick of timer control this time control will update the update panel control on certain period of time. We are loading some control with JQuery some with code behind. We call all function which need regualr update in timer tick event.

All works good at first time and untill few minutes that sudenly all get stop updating if we keep our browser open but then I referesh my browser manually all start working properly, again after few minutes it get stop updating.

I use following also but still no use

```
   var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
   prm.add_endRequest(function () .....
```

Comment: Try to use `pageLoaded` event of `PageRequestManager` instead of `endRequest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I removed Update Panel and Timer Control from page and I did work $.ajax and setIntervaltime.